# Node.js HTTP Server Child Process Won't Be Killed in Node.js

Tags: node.js, command-line, child-process

I am using Node.js (running on **Windows 10**) to make a server manager. I have other node http servers that are run using this node http server. I have a website that have start and stop buttons and they should start and stop the child process servers.

I am using

```
var spawn = require('child_process').spawn,
    serverCLI = {};

...

serverCLI[server.name].term = spawn('cd path/to/server/ && node server');
```

to get each server running. It works to start the servers, however where I am having issues is stopping the server.

The code for stopping the server is currently

```
serverCLI[server.name].term.kill('SIGKILL');
```

I have used exec instead of spawn originally. I tried using `SIGTERM` and `SIGINT`, but I have had no luck. The child server continues running.

I went as far as to grab the child process ID with `serverCLI[server.name].term.pid` and search the windows command line for the pid, but it doesn't exist.

What am I doing wrong? How can I fix this?

Comment: You mean the child process is still there, or it's _actually_ still doing something? Killed processes can still show up in tools like `top` or `ps` (as zombie). Once the parent process has exited, those processes will be cleaned up as well.

Answer (score 0):

Send a pkill on exec, there are many options you can use, maybe group all your servers on the same group process id, or find them by parent process, see pkill's man page.

```
    var processname = 'PrettyServer';
    var exec = require('child_process').exec;
    var child;

    child = exec(`pkill -i ${processname}`, function (error, stdout, stderr) {

        if (error !== null) {
            console.log('exec error: ' + error);
            // ETC
        } else {
            // ETC
        }
    });
```

Comment: In the post, it is noted that I am using windows. Sorry for the confusion. I will make that a bit more clear in the post.

Comment: Doesn't matter, try the Windows equiv, but on exec 'taskkill /IM xxxxx.exe /f' or similar